# Issues with Spyder v4.0.1 plotting and variable explorer

Tags: matplotlib, variables, plot, spyder, explorer

Guys need your help with Spyder v4.0.1.

1. For plotting I am not getting any axes, labels, titles on the plot even though I am declaring it in the code.
2. I am getting lot of irrelevant (or crap) data in Variable Explorer. I only want to see my declared variables 'x' and 'y'.

[image]

I have attached screenshot.

Comment: Please see the very clear warning posted in the console: The irrelevant variables you're talking about are generated because you're autoimporting Sympy and Pylab in the console. And importing those libraries is what gives the extra variables shown in the Variable Explorer. If you don't want to do that anymore, or don't understand how you activated those options, please run in a system terminal (cmd.exe or the Anaconda Prompt in your case, I think)  `spyder --reset` to start from a clean state in Spyder. I can't help you with the other problem, sorry.

Comment: I did the 'spyder --reset' earlier but did not work. However this morning I gave it another shot and now Variable Explorer is back to normal. Thanks! I still need urgent help with all the plotting issues. I have also tried the exact same code in Jupyter Notebook and it works flawlessly. I have to use Spyder as it is my first choice. All of the issue started after installing new anaconda last week. Is there a way to revert back to Spyder v3?

Comment: You can install in a different environment with this command: `conda create -n spyder-3 spyder=3`. Then you need to activate that env and start Spyder from it. Or you can simply go to the Anaconda entry in the Windows menu and find an new entry for Spyder 3.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I actually installed spyder 3.3 through pip and gave it a go. Same issue with the plots. Then thought I should update the package, again though pip. However, after update, spyder 3.3 crashed and now will fail to launch. I jumped to Spyder website and it says to install Spyder only though Anaconda or WinPython packages for stable releases....Atleast was able to confirm that Spyder 3.3 is showing the same plot (as the printscreen in my original post). I have jupyter and spyder activated in the env, is that what causing issues?

Comment: By using pip to install Spyder you effectively broke your Anaconda installation. So I'm afraid now you have to remove and reinstall Anaconda. Sorry but I've warned time and time again about that here in StackOverflow, but people still think that conda and pip are interchangeable, when effectively they are not.